# Quiero importar datos desde un archivo y tomarlos como enteros

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/cleal/Documents/Programación/Python/Programas/Archivos')

datos=open("datos.txt","r")

x1=int(datos.readline())
x2=int(datos.readline())
x3=int(datos.readline())
x4=int(datos.readline())
x5=int(datos.readline())

x=x1+x2
print(x)
datos.close()
```

En la línea donde    `x=x1+x2`    quiero que los datos importados sean tomados como enteros, por ejemplo: 
Si x1=1 y x2=2, entonces x=3.

Pero cuando imprimo `x` me salen los valores como cadena de caractéres.
¿Qué puedo hacer para que los valores sean tomados como enteros en lugar de carácteres?

Comment: Tu código me parece bien, de hecho lo puse tal cual en mi editor y se ejecutó sin problema, dando la respuesta correcta. El cambio a int lo haces en la línea en que lees los datos, por lo que es extraño el comportamiento. ¿Puedes compartir el contenido del archivo datos.txt?

Comment: Tal como bien comenta Javier tu código es correcto, es imposible que lo que comentas ocurra con ese código. La conversión a int ya lo haces en cada variable, x1. x2, x3, x4 y x5 o son enteros todos antes de llegar a la suma (y por tanto x también lo será) o tienes una excepción por recibir el constructor de int algo que no se puede convertir a entero... Algo más que este código no muestra está pasando...

Comment: Quieres decir que si x1 es 1 y x2 es 2 entonces el resultado x se te muestra como "12"?

Answer (score 0):

Como sabes que te esta poniendo una linea de caracteres? Que resultado esta dando?

```
type(x)
<type 'int'>
```

Usa este comando y deberia darte la respuesta que te pongo ahi.

Tambien puedes hacer esto:

```
x1=int(datos.readline().strip())
```

para eliminar caracteres no deseados(`\n` o `\r`).